# How do I show an element when another element has already been clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link,

```
<a href="manager_view.html">
    <p class="in_row">Jane Doe</p>
</a>
```

I want to show a checkmark, ✓, when Jane Doe has been clicked in the past. How would I do that?

Comment: do want to use jquery or pure JS?

Comment: Does "in the past" mean _ever_ or just during that session?

Comment: Your going to need to put some more information. Are you using Ajax? If you click the link the page will change anyway?

Comment: @MichaelWalter either is fine.

Comment: @jterry During that session

Answer (score 4):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g4JtJ/)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('in_row')[0].onclick = function()
{
    this.className = 'in_row clicked';
}
```

Or, if you have more than one:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('in_row');
for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++)
{
    rows[i].onclick = doclick; //this function is the above code
}
```

**CSS**

```
.clicked:before
{
    content:"✓";
}
```

Comment: You probably mean `rows[i].onclick = doclick;` instead of `= doclick();`

Comment: The issue with that is that it doesn't seem to save the check when you hit the back button and revisit the page

Comment: That's another issue entirely, then. You need to use AJAX, URL hashes, or a HTML form submission to save the values.

Answer (score 0):

You should use local storage http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp 
If you have more elements to store in it you can use  `JSON.stringify`
When you create a array of clicked elements you store it like this

```
  localStorage["rowsclick"] = JSON.stringify(elementsClickedArray);
```

And than to read that you need

```
 elementsClickedArray = JSON.parse(localStorage["rowsclick"]);
```